# query to sys.sql_modules returns no rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

The strange thing is that this worked a couple of weeks ago. I need to find all instances in all stored procedures where a certain phrase comes up. We have hundreds of stored procedures, so I wanted to use SQL to tell me where all of them are. I am using this statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
o.name, o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m
JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition LIKE '%view_cu_Account_Bills_b%'
```

The problem is that's returning zero rows. The issue appears to be with sys.sql_modules, as the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM sys.sql_modules
```

also contains zero rows. In a database with hundreds of stored procedures, why would sys.sql_modules not have anything in it? Am I missing something in MS SQL Server settings? (I'm using the 2008 edition).

Comment: You probably don't have sufficient permissions. [The visibility of the metadata in catalog views is limited to securables that a user either owns or on which the user has been granted some permission.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx)

Comment: that's what I would think as well, but it seems that I do have permissions... I am able to alter the stored procedures, and I frequently do so. And I certainly have the ability to view them... wouldn't that indicate that I should see them in sys.sql_modules?

Comment: And you are running the query under your user credentials and in the right database context?

Comment: ah, that was it, I was in the incorrect database context. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as Martin Smith suggested, first ensure that your query is in the right database context:

```sql
USE YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;
```

Otherwise, the following query won't return anything:

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM sys.sql_modules;
```